# javascript: fire Page onload event from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

The master page has a user control and Iframe. I would like to be able to reload the page in Iframe when the submit  button in user control is clicked. 
I want the data on the Iframe to refresh based on the User inputs in User control residing on Master page. Can we achieve it by JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible here is an example i have tried have a look at this.

- Created a page in which iframe will be placed.
- Created a button when clicked will refresh the iframe based on value
  input in textbox. Passed this value as querystring in src of iframe.
- Received this value as querystring in the page which will be loaded
  in iframe and based on query string refreshed the page.

Here is the code

This is the page in which iframe will be placed

```
<iframe src="Default.aspx" width="400" height="1000" id="iframe">

</iframe>
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="RefreshIframe()" />
<input type="text" id="txtID" />
```

Here is javascript function which will refresh the iframe

```
function RefreshIframe()
    {
        var id = $('#txtID').val();
        $('#iframe').attr("src", "default.aspx?id=" + id);

    }
```

Here is default.aspx page which will receive id as querystring

```
string id = "1";
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

Based on this id i have refreshed the data in page which will be shown in iframe.